# Jupyter notebook kernel dying while running gridsearchcv

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, classification

I am trying to build an Uplift model using the package pylift in python 3.7. Every time I try to do gridsearch the kernel dies and restarts. I have no clue what's causing this issue. Any input will be helpful. Please find below my code

```
import pylift 
from pylift import TransformedOutcome
up = TransformedOutcome(df_fil, col_treatment='Treatment',col_outcome='Outcome',col_policy='prop_scores',
                                stratify=df_fil['Treatment'],sklearn_model = XGBClassifier)
param_grid = {#'estimator': XGBClassifier(),
              'param_grid': {'max_depth': range(1,8,1)
              'learning_rate':[x/100 for x in range(1,12,4)],
              'colsample_bytree':[x/10 for x in range(3,10,1)],
              'min_child_weight':range(1,6,1),
              'scale_pos_weight':[x/10 for x in range(12,18,1)],
               }}
up.grid_search(**param_grid,cv=2)
```

While running the method grid_search, the kernel dies everytime, with the following error at jupyet notebook terminal

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

My data is having 1.5 million rows and 67 columns. I tried to reduce the number of fits in the grid_search by reducing the parameter range but it gives the same error. I am sure that it's not a memory issue as I am running it on AWS linux server with 64 GB RAM. I have been going crazy over this error for last one week. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9487

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't really help in my case, I am not using tensorflow. I think this is more of a scikit-learn issue.